# What are the health benefits of buying organic for fruits and vegetables on the EWG's Clean 15 List?

Tags: nutrition, commercial-farming, vegetables, fruits

I'm asking about fruits and vegetables in the [EWG's 2018 Clean Fifteen List](https://www.ewg.org/foodnews/clean-fifteen.php) which suggests that buying organic for these products is unnecessary because even when conventionally grown they are unlikely to contain pesticides:

- Sweetcorn
- Avocados
- Pineapples
- Cabbage
- Onions
- Frozen sweet peas
- Papayas
- Asparagus
- Mangoes
- Eggplant
- Honeydew melon
- Kiwi
- Cantaloupe
- Cauliflower
- Grapefruit

The Clean 15 and Dirty 12 lists are listed together, more readably, [here](https://globalnews.ca/news/3296249/the-dirty-dozen-and-clean-15-2017s-list-of-fruits-vegetables-with-the-most-pesticides/).

Assuming that cost isn't a difficulty, and I can pay for conventional and organic [varieties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_(botany)) (or is the correct term [form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_(botany))?) and assuming that both conventional and organic varieties are equally available, is there any benefit to buying organically grown produce from this group?

I still feel dicey and unsettled about buying conventional varieties. Notwithstanding these 15 foods' "cleanliness", isn't it more prudent to buy organic anyway? I buy organic:

- to try to dodge harmful pesticides, but I know organic foods still use pesticides;
- because some organic fruits and vegetables taste better.

Comment: Is this an issue that's really topical for veg*ans? Even omnivorous people eat fruits and vegetables :)

Answer (score 1):

As you state, *organic* does not mean that it does not contain pesticides. Standards on what [organic food](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_food) means vary significantly worldwide.

Costs aside...

> Organic farming features practices that cycle resources, promote
>   ecological balance, and conserve biodiversity.

**But** doctors [say](https://www.webmd.com/food-recipes/features/organic-food-better#1), answering your question

> There's really very limited information in people on actual health outcomes with consumption of these products.

and [also](https://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/nutrition-and-healthy-eating/in-depth/organic-food/art-20043880)

> there is limited information to draw conclusions about how these differences translate into overall health benefits.